# Taggit - how to initialize tags on creation?

Tags: django-taggit

```
class Test(models.Model):
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

In terminal:

```
t = Test(tags=["test_tag"])
t.tags //prints ['test_tag']
t.save()
```

However, when I load the object again and print it.

tags=[]

For some reason, it does not save properly.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the following [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206401/django-taggit-how-to-programmatically-create-tags) as well:

According to Taggit documentation:

```
apple = Food.objects.create(name="apple") 
apple.tags.add("red", "green", "delicious")
```

Comment: +1 for being the right answer. However, Taggit should support initialisation properly, in the way the questioner has tried.